# How to process a Image message with OpenCV from ROS2

Tags: python, opencv, ros2

i am trying to work a image message with OpenCV from ROS2

i tried to convert the ROS2 Image to OpenCV with  `bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2()` but it did not work.
here is my code:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
bridge = CvBridge()

class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info('1. I heard: "%s"' % msg.width)
        self.get_logger().info('2. I heard: "%s"' % msg.encoding)
        self.cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, 'bgra8')
        self.get_logger().info('3. I heard: "%s"' % self.cv_image)


def main(args=None):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

with the output:

```
[INFO] [1655741136.342080392] [minimal_subscriber]: 1. I heard: "512"
[INFO] [1655741136.342407086] [minimal_subscriber]: 2. I heard: "bgra8"
[INFO] [1655741136.343235582] [minimal_subscriber]: 3. I heard: "[[[180 130  70 255]
  [180 130  70 255]
  [180 130  70 255]
  ...
  [180 130  70 255]
  [180 130  70 255]
  [180 130  70 255]]
.....
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what does "did not work" mean practically? you got the data. I see it right there! you can simply show that with `cv.imshow` followed by `cv.waitKey`... if that is allowed within whatever framework ROS gives you

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz hey sorry for the confusion. I normally use OpenCV to process Image. Images i have has 3 BRG channel, but this has 4 channels: [180 130 70 255]. sure i can use numpy to delete the last channel. 
So my questions are: 
1. What is this channel? i thought standard OpenCV image format is with 3 channels(BRG)
2. Is there a better way to get direct 3 Channel information?

Comment: BRG doesn't exist. it's RGB or BGR. and you seem to have an alpha channel too, which you can ignore because it is probably all-255.

Answer (score 2):

You try to log the image data to the ROS Node Console, which can only display text.
If you want to actually display the image you need to:

1. Convert the CvImage back to a ROS Message.

```
image_message = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image, encoding="passthrough")
```

2. Publish the Image Message to a topic of your choice.

```
    try:
      self.image_pub.publish(image_message)
    except CvBridgeError as e:
      print(e)
```

3. Listen to your topic and display the Image with either RQT or the image_viewer topic:

   `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/your/topic/path`

Comment: hi, i displayed the text to see if i had the right data, so i can work with it after. I want a Matrix with 3 BGR channels just like the image if i get from a video data, for example `cap = cv.VideoCapture(filename)` and `__, frame = cap.read()`. The frame i should have has 3 channel, but the image i get from `self.cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, 'bgra8')` has 4 channels.

Answer (score 1):

**ros2 opencv-python demo**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node 
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
import cv2 
    
class SimplePubSub(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('simple_pub_sub')

        topic_name= 'video_frames'

        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(Image, topic_name , 10)
        self.timer = self.create_timer(0.1, self.timer_callback)

        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.br = CvBridge()

        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(Image, topic_name, self.img_callback, 10)
        self.subscription 
        self.br = CvBridge()


    def timer_callback(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()     
        if ret == True:
            self.publisher_.publish(self.br.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame))
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing video frame')


    def img_callback(self, data):
        self.get_logger().info('Receiving video frame')
        current_frame = self.br.imgmsg_to_cv2(data)
        cv2.imshow("camera", current_frame)   
        cv2.waitKey(1)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    simple_pub_sub = SimplePubSub()
    rclpy.spin(simple_pub_sub)
    simple_pub_sub.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```